# How to retrieve the status of Foreign Key constraint?

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have the SQL query for getting all the constraint names, but not sure how to get its status like whether it is enabled/disabled?

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint, 
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName,
type_desc AS ConstraintType,*
FROM sys.objects
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('FK_foo_bar', 'CnstIsDisabled')`

OR

Use [sys.foreign_keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) which has a column "is_disabled"

Comment: +1 I didn't find the `CnstIsDisabled` object property, but sys.foreign_keys worked. I went hunting around INFORMATION_SCHEMA but didn't find any flag here.

Comment: @mdma: are you Antoops who asked the question too?

Comment: no, but I was interested in the answer. (I also started researching the answer.)